# Azure iot sdk c sample: CMakeLists.txt works but make (Autotools) do not

Tags: azure, makefile, cmake, automake, azure-iot-sdk

I have the following problem and have no idea how to solve it.

I use the iothub_ll_client_x509_sample (azure iot sdk c) in a own project. If i use a CMakeLists.txt to compile the project all works fine. But if I use a Makefile.am (Autotools) to compile the programm I get several undefined references.

The CMakeLists.txt looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

set(AZUREIOT_INC_FOLDER ".." "/usr/local/include/azureiot" "/usr/local/include/azure_c_shared_utility" "/usr/local/include/azure_prov_client")

include_directories(${AZUREIOT_INC_FOLDER})

add_executable(sample_app azureSendingMessageMain.cc)

target_link_libraries(sample_app
    iothub_client_mqtt_transport
    iothub_client_amqp_transport
    iothub_client_http_transport
    iothub_client
    umqtt
    prov_auth_client
    hsm_security_client
    uhttp
    aziotsharedutil
    parson
    uuid
    pthread
    curl
    ssl
    crypto
    m
)
```

My Makefile.am looks like this

```
bin_PROGRAMS = azureSendingMessage

azureSendingMessage_SOURCES = azureSendingMessageMain.cc 

azureSendingMessage_CPPFLAGS = -isystem/usr/local/include/azureiot 

azureSendingMessage_LDADD = /usr/local/lib/libiothub_client_mqtt_transport.a \
                    /usr/local/lib/libiothub_client_amqp_transport.a \
                    /usr/local/lib/libiothub_client_http_transport.a \
                    /usr/local/lib/libiothub_client.a \
                    /usr/local/lib/libumqtt.a \
                    /usr/local/lib/libprov_auth_client.a \
                    /usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a \
                    /usr/local/lib/libuhttp.a \
                    /usr/local/lib/libaziotsharedutil.a \
                    /usr/local/lib/libparson.a \
                    -luuid \
                    -lpthread \
                    -lcurl \
                    -lssl \
                    -lcrypto \
                    -lm
```

So both have the complete same order of linking librarys.

If i try to compile the program with the Makefile I get the following errors

```
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -Wall -Werror -Wformat-security -Wignored-qualifiers -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wpointer-arith -Wundef -Wduplicated-cond -Wshift-negative-value -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wfloat-conversion -Wsized-deallocation -Wlogical-not-parentheses -Wno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -pipe -fno-implement-inlines  -O3   -o iotProcess iotProcess-iotProcess.o iotProcess-TMPMsgIot.o iotProcess-IotCloudComm.o iotProcess-MessageHandler.o iotProcess-jsonUtil.o /usr/local/lib/libiothub_client_mqtt_transport.a /usr/local/lib/libiothub_client_amqp_transport.a /usr/local/lib/libiothub_client_http_transport.a /usr/local/lib/libiothub_client.a /usr/local/lib/libumqtt.a /usr/local/lib/libprov_auth_client.a /usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a /usr/local/lib/libuhttp.a /usr/local/lib/libaziotsharedutil.a ../common/libbpng.la ../configuration/libconfiguration.la ../common/tmpMsg/libtmpmsg.la ../common/util/libutil.la /opt/telemotive/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libtmtrace.la /opt/telemotive/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libtmutil.la /opt/telemotive/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libtmproc.la /opt/telemotive/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libtmio.la /opt/telemotive/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libtmpbus.la -lpthread -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lm -lxerces-c -luuid /usr/local/lib/libparson.a -lmscan_api -lmdis_api
libtool: link: g++ -Wall -Werror -Wformat-security -Wignored-qualifiers -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wpointer-arith -Wundef -Wduplicated-cond -Wshift-negative-value -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wfloat-conversion -Wsized-deallocation -Wlogical-not-parentheses -Wno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -pipe -fno-implement-inlines -O3 -o .libs/iotProcess iotProcess-iotProcess.o iotProcess-TMPMsgIot.o iotProcess-IotCloudComm.o iotProcess-MessageHandler.o iotProcess-jsonUtil.o  /usr/local/lib/libiothub_client_mqtt_transport.a /usr/local/lib/libiothub_client_amqp_transport.a /usr/local/lib/libiothub_client_http_transport.a /usr/local/lib/libiothub_client.a /usr/local/lib/libumqtt.a /usr/local/lib/libprov_auth_client.a /usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a /usr/local/lib/libuhttp.a /usr/local/lib/libaziotsharedutil.a ../common/.libs/libbpng.so ../configuration/.libs/libconfiguration.so ../common/tmpMsg/.libs/libtmpmsg.so ../common/util/.libs/libutil.so /opt/telemotive/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libtmtrace.so /opt/telemotive/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libtmutil.so /opt/telemotive/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libtmproc.so /opt/telemotive/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libtmio.so /opt/telemotive/lib/i686-linux-gnu/libtmpbus.so -lpthread /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so -lssl -lcrypto -lm -lxerces-c -luuid /usr/local/lib/libparson.a -lmscan_api -lmdis_api -pthread
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_riot.c.o): In function `generate_root_ca_info':
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `DERInitContext'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to `DERInitContext'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0xe6): undefined reference to `X509GetDeviceCertTBS'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x150): undefined reference to `RiotCrypt_Sign'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x1b4): undefined reference to `X509MakeRootCert'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x239): undefined reference to `DERtoPEM'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x2e5): undefined reference to `X509GetDEREcc'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x34d): undefined reference to `DERtoPEM'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_riot.c.o): In function `produce_device_cert':
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x409): undefined reference to `DERInitContext'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x426): undefined reference to `X509GetDeviceCertTBS'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x48e): undefined reference to `RiotCrypt_Sign'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x4f3): undefined reference to `X509MakeDeviceCert'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x56e): undefined reference to `DERInitContext'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x58b): undefined reference to `X509GetDERCsrTbs'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x5f3): undefined reference to `RiotCrypt_Sign'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x658): undefined reference to `X509GetDERCsr'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x6c9): undefined reference to `DERInitContext'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x6e6): undefined reference to `X509GetDeviceCertTBS'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x74e): undefined reference to `RiotCrypt_Sign'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x7b0): undefined reference to `X509MakeDeviceCert'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x832): undefined reference to `DERtoPEM'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_riot.c.o): In function `produce_alias_key_cert':
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x8c6): undefined reference to `DERtoPEM'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_riot.c.o): In function `produce_alias_key_pair':
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x976): undefined reference to `DERInitContext'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x9d9): undefined reference to `X509GetDEREcc'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0xa4e): undefined reference to `DERtoPEM'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_riot.c.o): In function `produce_device_id_public':
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0xb01): undefined reference to `DERInitContext'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0xb25): undefined reference to `X509GetDEREccPub'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0xb9a): undefined reference to `DERtoPEM'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_riot.c.o): In function `process_riot_key_info':
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0xcc8): undefined reference to `RiotCrypt_Hash'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0xd3f): undefined reference to `RiotCrypt_DeriveEccKey'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0xdb4): undefined reference to `RiotCrypt_Hash2'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0xe31): undefined reference to `RiotCrypt_DeriveEccKey'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0xf84): undefined reference to `DERInitContext'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0xfb1): undefined reference to `X509GetAliasCertTBS'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x101c): undefined reference to `RiotCrypt_Sign'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x1084): undefined reference to `X509MakeAliasCert'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_riot.c.o): In function `hsm_client_x509_init':
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x1295): undefined reference to `DiceSHA256'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x12b9): undefined reference to `DiceSHA256_2'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_riot.c.o): In function `hsm_client_riot_create_leaf_cert':
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x1c22): undefined reference to `DERInitContext'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x1c3f): undefined reference to `X509GetDeviceCertTBS'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x1cad): undefined reference to `RiotCrypt_Sign'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x1d15): undefined reference to `X509MakeDeviceCert'
hsm_client_riot.c:(.text+0x1de9): undefined reference to `DERtoPEM'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_tpm.c.o): In function `GetEkTemplate':
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `ToTpmaObject'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_tpm.c.o): In function `GetSrkTemplate':
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to `ToTpmaObject'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_tpm.c.o): In function `dps_umarshal_array':
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x114): undefined reference to `UINT32_Unmarshal'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_tpm.c.o): In function `unmarshal_array':
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x1f2): undefined reference to `UINT32_Unmarshal'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_tpm.c.o): In function `marshal_array_values':
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x32b): undefined reference to `UINT32_Unmarshal'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x452): undefined reference to `UINT32_Unmarshal'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x579): undefined reference to `UINT32_Unmarshal'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x6a2): undefined reference to `TPM2B_PUBLIC_Unmarshal'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x742): undefined reference to `UINT16_Unmarshal'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x7de): undefined reference to `TPM2B_PRIVATE_Unmarshal'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_tpm.c.o): In function `create_tpm_session':
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x8a1): undefined reference to `TSS_StartAuthSession'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x907): undefined reference to `TSS_PolicySecret'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_tpm.c.o): In function `insert_key_in_tpm':
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0xa94): undefined reference to `TPM2B_ID_OBJECT_Unmarshal'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0xaf4): undefined reference to `TPM2B_ENCRYPTED_SECRET_Unmarshal'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0xb54): undefined reference to `TPM2B_PRIVATE_Unmarshal'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0xbb4): undefined reference to `TPM2B_ENCRYPTED_SECRET_Unmarshal'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0xc13): undefined reference to `TPM2B_PUBLIC_Unmarshal'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0xc73): undefined reference to `UINT16_Unmarshal'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0xcee): undefined reference to `TPM2_ActivateCredential'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0xd7b): undefined reference to `TPM2_Import'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0xe2d): undefined reference to `ToTpmaObject'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0xecc): undefined reference to `TSS_Create'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0xf46): undefined reference to `TPM2_Load'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0xfb4): undefined reference to `TPM2_EvictControl'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0xfdc): undefined reference to `TPM2_EvictControl'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x1036): undefined reference to `TPM2_FlushContext'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_tpm.c.o): In function `decrypt_data':
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x1131): undefined reference to `TSS_GetTpmProperty'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x11f8): undefined reference to `TPM2B_ID_OBJECT_Unmarshal'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x1258): undefined reference to `TPM2B_ENCRYPTED_SECRET_Unmarshal'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x12b8): undefined reference to `TPM2B_PRIVATE_Unmarshal'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x1318): undefined reference to `TPM2B_ENCRYPTED_SECRET_Unmarshal'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x1377): undefined reference to `TPM2B_PUBLIC_Unmarshal'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x13d7): undefined reference to `UINT16_Unmarshal'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x14fa): undefined reference to `TPM2_ActivateCredential'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_tpm.c.o): In function `initialize_tpm_device':
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x15dc): undefined reference to `TSS_CreatePwAuthSession'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x1632): undefined reference to `Initialize_TPM_Codec'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x16a9): undefined reference to `TSS_CreatePersistentKey'
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x1720): undefined reference to `TSS_CreatePersistentKey'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_tpm.c.o): In function `hsm_client_tpm_destroy':
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x1885): undefined reference to `Deinit_TPM_Codec'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_tpm.c.o): In function `hsm_client_tpm_get_endorsement_key':
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x1a8f): undefined reference to `TPM2B_PUBLIC_Marshal'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_tpm.c.o): In function `hsm_client_tpm_get_storage_key':
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x1c63): undefined reference to `TPM2B_PUBLIC_Marshal'
/usr/local/lib/libhsm_security_client.a(hsm_client_tpm.c.o): In function `hsm_client_tpm_sign_data':
hsm_client_tpm.c:(.text+0x1e01): undefined reference to `SignData'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:570: recipe for target 'iotProcess' failed
make: *** [iotProcess] Error 1
```

I really have no idea why the program isn't compiling with make (Autotools) but with CMakeLists.txt.

The problem is that there is a need to use make and autotools so use CMakeLists.txt is no option :(

Hopefully anyone can help me to figure out whats went wron with the make (autotools) and the Makefile.am

**EDIT:**

Ok I played around long time and figuerd out the problem but no solution.

As I said I use the azure iot sdk for c.
If i try to use the MQTT_Protocol, I get undefined reference errors.

The lines

```
IOTHUB_DEVICE_CLIENT_LL_HANDLE device_ll_handle;
device_ll_handle = IoTHubClientCore_LL_CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, MQTT_Protocol);
```

produce the error. I reorder the libraries in all exist combinations but still get this undefined references....

Can anyone help me? Do i miss some libraries to use the MQTT_Protocol?
I still include the libiothub_client_mqtt_transport.a, libuamqp.a and libumqtt.a

Comment: Well, you have to look at the command line being invoked by make.  Just showing the errors won't help: you need to see what the link line looks like and see if your libraries are there, and in the right order.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @MadScientist it is the same order like in the CMakeLists.txt. What you mean with i should look at the command line? I compile it with the autotools and the Makefile.am. Do you mean I should try to compile it on my own with gcc?

Comment: When make runs a command, it prints out what command it is running. So if you run  make, you'll see a line starting with gcc, with a list of all of the .o files it is linking together. This should be right before the error message. This is be helpful for figuring out what went wrong.

Comment: ok I edit my post and insert the complete console output if I execute make